# Verifying whether applications send email

Tags: .net, code-analysis

We have quite a large suite of dot Net applications, large source code base. Is there a quick and easy way to identify all those applications that send email or make use of our SMTP servers? The obvious ways would be doing a text search for Mail, SMTP etc. Also reviewing config files... is there any way that is quicker, more complete or accurate?

Comment: You could use a static analysis tool such as NDepend http://www.ndepend.com/ to determine dependency on .NET Smtp classes.

Comment: Are you looking for vanilla code presumably written by your organization on purpose that does this, or for maliciously inserted code that may be disguised?  That will change the answer radically, with "finding malicious code" not likely to be easy or quick.

Comment: Vanilla code, no malicious code suspected

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) if you have many processes - it captures all web requests and shows you what app just sent/received data.

Comment: I think that's an interesting idea but how will that find apps that are capable of sending mail but hardly ever do?

Comment: Oh and does Fiddler even work with SMTP? I wasn't aware that it did?